# How do I restructure a json in YAML?

Tags: google-bigquery, yaml, google-workflows

I would like to send data from an API to a BigQuery table with Google Workflows (YAML format).
But the API response that I want to send to BigQuery table does not match the "insertAll" BigQuery connector feature.

```YAML
main:
   params: [input]
   steps:
   - retrieveMatomoData:
       call: http.get
       args:
           url: https://.....
       result: matomoData
 
   - insertAll:
           call: googleapis.bigquery.v2.tabledata.insertAll
           args:
               datasetId: myDatasetId
               projectId: myProjectId
               tableId: myTableId
               body:
               "rows": [
           {
        json: should be the full "matomoData" response
       }
]
```

The response structure of the API I use is:

```YAML
{
 "body": [
    {
    …
    },
    {
    …
    }
]
```

(which is an array that corresponds to several rows to insert)
It does not match with the structure to insert rows in Bigquery:

```YAML
"rows": [
           {
        json: …
       },
    json: …
]
```

Do you have any idea of how can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

While the Workflows syntax and standard library can perform simple data extraction and transformation, larger JSON transformations are likely unwieldy inside Workflows for now. I'd recommend using a Cloud Function with a JSON transformation library.